# KrakenJS - Adaro configuration

Tags: node.js, kraken.js

I can't seem to work out where I can set adaro configs for kraken. I am looking to add some custom dust helpers but i'm not really sure how to implement this, after much googling I thought i'd try SO to see if others had the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes in the configuration for the view engines, for engine-munger:

`"view engines": {
        "dust": {
            "module": "engine-munger",
            "renderer": {
                "method": "js",
                "arguments": [
                    {
                        "cache": true,
                        "helpers": [
                            {
                                "name": "dust-makara-helpers",
                                "arguments": [ { "localeRoot": "path:locales" } ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "views": "config:express.views",
                        "view engine": "config:express.view engine",
                        "specialization": "config:specialization"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },`

See the `helpers` key? There.